# Best method to combine defined props in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string-concatenation, react-props, conditional-operator

I have one component which receives props of user details like `first_name` and `last_name`. It is possible that either one of `first_name` and `last_name` to be `undefined` or both are `undefined`.

I want to receive it inside a parent component and display it by combining like this :

```
contactName = {props.client_firstname || props.client_lastname ?
           props.client_firstname +" " +props.client_lastname : "N/A" }
```

What is the best method to check if the value is set for `first_name` and `last_name` inside the above ternary condition and combine only defined values?

Answer (score 1):

You can set default prop-types

```
YoursComponent.defaultProps = {
  client_firstname: '',
  client_lastname: ''
};

contactName={props.client_firstname +" " +props.client_lastname }
```

No need of ternary operator. In case if it is undefined then it will get default value from default props.

Thanks

Comment: If first is undefined, the concated result would be ` x` (start with a blank)

Comment: I understand yours questions. I am just giving one direction from react point of view. If he  thinks that this is the right approach then he can enhance this logic. :)

Comment: @QubaishBhatti Did any post solved your problem? Kindly inform us if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
contactName = {
                ([props.client_firstname, props.client_lastname])
                .join(" ")
                .trim()
              }
```

Example:

```js
console.log(["FirstName", undefined].join(" ").trim());

console.log([null, "LastName"].join(" ").trim());

console.log(["FirstName", "LastName"].join(" ").trim());

console.log([null, undefined].join(" ").trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to store the two props,

then [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), finally add the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for `N/A`

```js
const generator = list => {
  const result = list.join(" ").trim();
  return result ? result : "N/A";
};

console.log('>' + generator(["first", "second"]) + '<');
console.log('>' + generator(["first", undefined]) + '<');
console.log('>' + generator([undefined, "second"]) + '<');
console.log('>' + generator([undefined, undefined]) + '<');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getFullName( props = {} ){
  const{ client_firstname='', client_lastname='' } = props;

  let SEPERATOR = client_firstname && client_lastname ? " ": "";
  
  return `${client_firstname}${SEPERATOR}${client_lastname}`
}

console.log( getFullName(
 { client_firstname:'stack', client_lastname:'overflow' }
))

console.log( getFullName(
 { client_firstname:'', client_lastname:'overflow' }
))

console.log( getFullName(
 { client_lastname:'overflow' }
))

console.log(getFullName(
 { client_firstname:'stack', client_lastname:undefined}
))

console.log(getFullName(
  {}
))
console.log(getFullName())
```